# (Vue.js | Jest | Babel) Unexpected token when importing specific vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I'm importing a vue file with just scripts in vue file with only template tag 
And then I import js files to help me to do what I need 
In this last imports are the problem (I think), but is just this file, because I already tested with another ones and test passes

PS: sorry for my newbie question and my english, this is my very first question. Thank you for your attention

sales.test.js

```
import ApexChart from 'vue-apexcharts'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

import salesPage from '../src/views/vendas/Vendas'
```

package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "vue"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^[^.]+.(vue|jsx)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": ["jest-serializer-vue"]
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": 2,
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true,
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 2,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

functions.js

```
'use strict'

import moment from 'moment'

export function dateFormatter(date) {
  return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
}

export function changeInitialDate(date) {
  if (date) {
    this.disabledDatesEnd = null
    this.disabledDatesEnd = new Object()
    this.disabledDatesEnd.to = new Date(date)
  }
}

export function changeFinalDate(date) {
  if (date) {
    this.disabledDatesStart = null
    this.disabledDatesStart = new Object()
    this.disabledDatesStart.from = new Date(date)
  }
}

export function cnpjFormatter(cnpj) {
  return cnpj.toString().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g, '')
}
```

error

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /home/victor/development/accesys/AccCRM/Sources/cliente-web-clientes/unknown: Unexpected token (16:0)

      14 |   changeFinalDate,
      15 |   cnpjFormatter,
    > 16 | } from "../../functions";
         | ^
      17 | 
      18 | import {
      19 |   onClassChange,

      at Object._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
      at Object.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:55:17)
      at Object.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:39:17)
      at Object.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:139:16)
      at Object.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1186:20)
      at Object.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/plugins/jsx/index.js:535:22)
      at Object.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:563:23)
      at Object.parseUpdate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:543:21)
      at Object.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:527:17)
      at Object.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:343:23)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.524s
```

Comment: If you could share your files from your `functions` folder that would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be the trailing comma in your import?

From this:

```js
import { changeFinalDate, cnpjFormatter, } from "../../functions";
                                       ^
```

To this:

```
import { changeFinalDate, cnpjFormatter } from "../../functions";
```

Comment: This worked, but now I have another error in the name of the component, like:
export default { name: 'Vendas' -> unexpected token, expected "}"

Comment: Try removing the curly braces from your import statement. As far as I recall you only use the curly braces on import when a function is exported with the `defaults` flag in js. so try:  `import changeFinalDate, cnpjFormatter  from "../../functions";`